# How to color code snippet in Django template

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I am looking at coloring code on one of my Django page, the way PyCharm does it for instance.

```
def my_function(a):
    return a + 5


print(my_function(10))
```

displayed with colors such as (the background doesn't have to be black):

[image]

Is there an easy solution to capture anything within the `<pre><code></code></pre>` tags and applies this color code? Writing my own Django filter for this looks like an arduous task.

Comment: Isn't this about your IDE rather than Django? You should be able to install the relevant packages

Comment: I mean, I am trying to display code on my website as it is, and I was wondering if I could color code it the way PyCharm does it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to highlight python, or any other language, code / syntax you need [pygments](https://pygments.org/)

**pygments** is used in [sphinx](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/), the defacto doc generator, to highlight syntax.

i would like to point you to this sub-project of **django**: [djangosnippets.org](http://djangosnippets.org), the repo is already available on **github** ([here](https://github.com/django/djangosnippets.org)), it's a kind of site that hosts snippets for django using pygments to highlight syntaxes, the point here is to have a look at the code and get inspired.

refer to the doc https://pygments.org/docs/styles/ to learn more about howto write your own style or even more your own lexer.